# xml and xslt help?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<table name="ASSETS_TABLE" statement-type="INSERT"> 
    <column name="ASSET_ID">string(/assets/asset/value())</column> 
    <column name="ASSET_VALUE"> 
    <option name="VALUE_GREATER_THEN_0">/assets/asset > 0</option> 
    <option name="VALUE_LESS_THEN_0">/assets/asset < 0</option> 
    <option name="OTHERWISE">1</option> 
    </column> 
    <column name="ASSET_DESCRIPTION">string(/assets/asset/text())</column> 
    </table>
```

From the above XML, i need to get the values of the attributes (i.e name). For column and option nodes, how would you go about using a loop to get the value of the attribute and using it as an element name or a variable name and the value of the column node as value of the new element or variable.

So I'd want something like

```
<ASSET_VALUE>
<VALUE_GREATER_THEN_0>/assets/asset > 0</VALUE_GREATER_THEN_0> 
<VALUE_LESS_THEN_0>/assets/asset < 0</VALUE_LESS_THEN_0> 
<OTHERWISE>1</OTHERWISE> 
</ASSET_VALUE> 
<ASSET_DESCRIPTION>string(/assets/asset/text())</ASSET_DESCRIPTION>
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921977/xslt-transformation-dynamic-element-names/7922068#7922068).

You didn't specify what you wanted done for `table`, so I guessed.

Using your XML input (modified to be well formed):

```
<table name="ASSETS_TABLE" statement-type="INSERT"> 
  <column name="ASSET_ID">string(/assets/asset/value())</column> 
  <column name="ASSET_VALUE"> 
    <option name="VALUE_GREATER_THEN_0">/assets/asset > 0</option> 
    <option name="VALUE_LESS_THEN_0">/assets/asset &lt; 0</option> 
      <option name="OTHERWISE">1</option> 
  </column> 
  <column name="ASSET_DESCRIPTION">string(/assets/asset/text())</column> 
</table>
```

With this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table|column|option">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <!--
      Uncomment the following "xsl:copy-of" if you want to 
      retain any attributes other than "name":
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name() != 'name']"/>
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces this output:

```
<ASSETS_TABLE>
   <ASSET_ID>string(/assets/asset/value())</ASSET_ID>
   <ASSET_VALUE>
      <VALUE_GREATER_THEN_0>/assets/asset &gt; 0</VALUE_GREATER_THEN_0>
      <VALUE_LESS_THEN_0>/assets/asset &lt; 0</VALUE_LESS_THEN_0>
      <OTHERWISE>1</OTHERWISE>
   </ASSET_VALUE>
   <ASSET_DESCRIPTION>string(/assets/asset/text())</ASSET_DESCRIPTION>
</ASSETS_TABLE>
```