# Using Position Method in for-each Loop to Access Node Index / Dynamic Node Creation

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I’m trying to convert an Excel spreadsheet saved as XML to an actual XML document (remove all the references to formatting and just get my data).   The first row are the headers which should be node names, and the rest of the rows are the data.    The XML will be used in a Windows forms application and the transformation will be done through the
[XslTransform class of the XML namespace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322).

I cannot use interop to access Excel because the machines the program will be used on do not have MS Office.  Saving as CSV and reading the file will fail if any of the columns contain the delimiter.  I don’t want to just write an XML file or hardcode information because it will require updating when the spreadsheet changes.   So I believe dynamically generating XML is the best option.

For simplicity’s sake I have removed most of the extraneous information from the generated XML file to show just the worksheet I am interested in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Worksheet Name="AttributionImages">
  <Table ExpandedColumnCount="5" ExpandedRowCount="2" FullColumns="1"
   FullRows="1">
   <Column AutoFitWidth="0" Width="73.5"/>
   <Column AutoFitWidth="0" Width="84"/>
   <Column AutoFitWidth="0" Width="121.5"/>
   <Column AutoFitWidth="0" Width="146.25"/>
   <Column AutoFitWidth="0" Width="124.5"/>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">Source</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">PicSet</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">License</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">Website</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">Image1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s21" HRef="http://www.website.com/"><Data Type="String">Artist </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">FreeIcons</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data Type="String">Creative Commons Attribution</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s21" HRef="http://www.website.com/"><Data  
Type="String">http://www.website.com</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
```

**My XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Worksheet">
<xsl:element name="{@Name}">
    <xsl:for-each select="Table/Row">
        <xsl:if test="(position( )) &gt; 1">
                <Image>
                <xsl:for-each select="Cell">
                        <xsl:element name="{/Worksheet/Table/Row[1]/Cell[position()]/Data}">
                        <!-- <countNo><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></countNo> -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="Data"/>
                        </xsl:element>     
                </xsl:for-each>
                </Image>
        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>  
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I credit  answers on the following threads for helping me develop the above XSLT:

- [Counter inside xsl:for-each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93511/counter-inside-xslfor-each-loop)
- [XSLT Transformation - dynamic    element names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921977/xslt-transformation-dynamic-element-names)

**Expected output:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <AttributionImages>
 <Image>
  <Name>Image1 </Name> 
  <Source>Artist</Source> 
  <PicSet>FreeIcons</PicSet> 
  <License>Creative Commons Attribution</License> 
  <Website>http://www.Website.com</Website> 
  </Image>
  </AttributionImages>
```

**Actual Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <AttributionImages>
 <Image>
  <Name>Image1 </Name> 
  <Name>Artist</Name> 
  <Name>FreeIcons</Name> 
  <Name>Creative Commons Attribution</Name> 
  <Name>http://www.Website.com</Name> 
  </Image>
  </AttributionImages>
```

For some reason “/Worksheet/Table/Row[1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322)/Cell[position()]/Data” is always equal to the first cell of the first row (1 = name).  If I replace position() with the number 1-5 it access the correct index.  Additionally, `<countNo><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></countNo>` which I have commented out, will output the correct loop count.  What do I need to specify for the cell[] index value to access all the nodes in the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you do `/Worksheet/Table/Row1/Cell[position()]/Data` the call to "position()" will be in a different context to your xsl:for-each loop, it will be the context of selecting "/Worksheet/Table/Row1/Cell"

What you need to do, is store the position in a variable before first, and then reference that in your xpath expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
<xsl:element name="{/Worksheet/Table/Row[1]/Cell[$position]/Data}">
```

Actually, it might be slightly more efficient to use a key to look up the headers here. Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="header" match="Table/Row[1]/Cell" use="count(preceding-sibling::Cell) + 1"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Worksheet">
      <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
         <xsl:for-each select="Table/Row">
            <xsl:if test="(position( )) &gt; 1">
               <Image>
                  <xsl:for-each select="Cell">
                     <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
                     <xsl:element name="{key('header', $position)/Data/text()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Data"/>
                     </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </Image>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works perfectly for what I’m trying to do.  I’m am XSLT newbie and had no ideal about the Key function.